# Force sqlite3 (on python) to store data sequentially

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, numpy

I'm using the code given below for only two operations:

1. Inserting numpy arrays at the very bottom of the database
2. Yanking the very first array and then deleting it

The data I'm working with is going to be very big (think in the low terabytes) and **I want the data to be stored and retrieved sequentially on my hard drive** (like the old tape storage). Now I have searched through the land, far and wide and I'm not sure if this is already automatically  done on sqlite3 or if its even possible.

```
import io
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

class SQLNumpy():
    """This will insert a numpy array into a sqlite3 instance"""
    def __init__(self, db_name):
        # Converts np.array to TEXT when inserting
        sqlite3.register_adapter(np.ndarray, self.adapt_array)
        # Converts TEXT to np.array when selecting
        sqlite3.register_converter("array", self.convert_array)

        self.db_name = db_name
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        arr ARRAY);""")

    def adapt_array(self, arr):
        out = io.BytesIO()
        np.save(out, arr)
        out.seek(0)
        return sqlite3.Binary(out.read())

    def convert_array(self, text):
        out = io.BytesIO(text)
        out.seek(0)
        return np.load(out)

    def insert(self, arr):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO data (arr) values (?)", (arr, ))

    def first_select(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT arr FROM data LIMIT 1")
        self.data = self.cursor.fetchall()

    def first_delete(self):
        self.cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM data WHERE id in (
            SELECT id FROM data LIMIT 1)""")

    def commit(self):
        self.conn.commit()

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()

x = np.random.rand(8760)

x_sql = SQLNumpy("test.db")
x_sql.insert(x)
x_sql.insert(x) # Add two and then remove one. 

x_sql.first_select()                        
print(x_sql.data)                           
x_sql.first_delete()
                        
x_sql.commit()                              
x_sql.close()
```

Comment: That is nothing to be solved in code, most likely neither in the database. Nowadays on modern drives not even the OS has a word on where exactly data is stored.

Comment: Hmmm, and is there no way to connect to a lower level API for direct disk access on python? I will be running my code on an Ubuntu server but can change it to any Linux distro that offers this service.

Comment: Sounds like you did not read my comment at all.

Comment: I did read your comment, that's why I asked if there may be another distro (or OS) that allows this. Or a low level API, some process on the computer has to know where the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 100% guaranteed way to do this.

As @KlausD. points out, even the lowest software access to a drive can't guarantee anything because modern disks will move data around without the software knowing about it (usually to fix broken sectors).

Your best bet is to write the data into one file, all at once.

(If you are feeling insane, you could forego a filesystem and, in Linux, write the data directly to the `/dev/sdX` block device node, which is the closest you are going to get to a contiguous space in software-land, but you'll either have to be really careful to access just the data correctly or waste tons of times reinventing a filesystem)

SQLite certainly will not help you with this.